# Как сделать, чтобы при hover на картинку она затемнялась и появлялся текст внутри нее?

Tags: html, css

Весь Интернет перерыл, не нашел ничего толкового. Смысл прост: при наведении мышью на картинку она должна затемняться чуть-чуть. И внутри блока-картинки появлялся текст. Прошу помочь.

Answer (score 7):

http://jsfiddle.net/8h177njo/

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  background: url('http://moyhutor.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/ogurec1.jpg') no-repeat center top;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

p {
  display: none;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI';
  line-height: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  animation: fade .5s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

div:hover p {
  display: block;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Text</p>
</div>
```

или так

http://jsfiddle.net/a0h9uzrw/

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  background: url('http://moyhutor.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/ogurec1.jpg') no-repeat center top;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

p {
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI';
  line-height: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  transition: .5s ease;
}

div:hover p {
  opacity: 1;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Для плавного затемнения можно добавить `div, p{ transition: all 1s; };` http://jsfiddle.net/z7qsqmon/

Answer (score 0):

Пара идей для вдохновения (codrops):

1. [демо](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CaptionHoverEffects/) и [статья](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/06/18/caption-hover-effects/)
2. [демо](http://tympanus.net/Development/HoverEffectIdeas/) и [статья](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/06/19/ideas-for-subtle-hover-effects/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="list--image">
    <img src="12.jpg" class="image">
</div>



.list--image {
    background: black;
    opacity: 1;
}

.list--image:hover .image {
   opacity: 0.8;
}
```